# How to convert a simple hash to json in Perl?

Tags: json, perl, encoding, utf-8, hash

I'm using the following code to encode a simple hash

```
use JSON;

my $name = "test";
my $type = "A";
my $data = "1.1.1.1";
my $ttl  = 84600;

@rec_hash = ('name'=>$name, 'type'=>$type,'data'=>$data,'ttl'=>$ttl);
```

but I get the following error:

```
hash- or arrayref expected <not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this>
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your code seems to be missing some significant chunks, so let's add in the missing bits (I'll make some assumptions here) and fix things as we go.

Add missing boilerplate.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $name = "test";
my $type = "A";
my $data = "1.1.1.1";
my $ttl  = 84600;
```

Make the hash a hash and not an array and don't forget to localise it: `my %`

```
my %rec_hash = ('name'=>$name, 'type'=>$type,'data'=>$data,'ttl'=>$ttl);
```

Actually use the `encode_json` method (passing it a hashref):

```
my $json = encode_json \%rec_hash;
```

Output the result:

```
print $json;
```

And that works as I would expect without errors.

Comment: Thank you so much in pointing me to these errors. I'm learning Perl and I didn't notice I was trying to use an array as a hash lol Thx again +1!

Comment: Lacking that backslash (`\%rec_hash`) was my problem

Answer (score 4):

Try `%rec_hash = ...` instead. `@` indicates a list/array, while `%` indicates a hash.