# Perl: Modify data structure in .pm file at runtime

Tags: perl

I have a .pm file where i have a data structure something like this:

```
my $var = {  
    "xyz" => {
        "pqr" => {
            "all" => "123",
        },
    },
    "abc" => {
        "zzz" => {
            "f"  => "foo1",
            "n"  => "foo2",
            "g"  => "foo3", 
        },
    },
};

sub getDataStructure() {
    return $var;
}
```

This `getDataStructure` method is widely used by various programs on my system.

What I want is to have a script which can write more entries into `$var`. Let us assume that these values are user inputs.

I read the file line by line, went on until I got `};` of `$var`, and now I want to go back one line and use `print FH $newContent` where FH is my file handle.

How do I do that? I tried using the `seek` function but can not figure out way to do it properly

Please note: this question is not about how to write Perl hashes into file. This is about some trick which can modify an existing .pm file and write some new values into the data structure I mentioned.

Comment: I would recommend that you use JSON format and serialize the hash to file. See [How to convert a simple hash to json in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463919/how-to-convert-a-simple-hash-to-json-in-perl)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352298

Comment: Also, you know this is a really bad idea, right?

Comment: @mob : I understand. But I have to do it this way considering the whole architecture of this software system I am dealing with

Comment: This is such a bad idea, maybe you should talk about the problem you're trying to solve with it. We might be able to come up with something better.

Comment: You mean that your script only has access to itself, but not to the rest of the filesystem or to a database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a terrible idea.  I'm not going to bother answering it, all the solutions will just add an unmaintainable mess on top of whatever unmaintainable mess you're maintaining.  There are much better ways to alter a private variable in a .pm file that don't make things worse by trying to parse and alter Perl code.

The simplest thing to do is call `getDataStructure` (I hope `$var` and `getDataStructure` are not the real names) and modify the returned reference.

```
my $data = getDataStructure;
$data->{new_thing} = { new => "stuff" };
```

If for some reason this doesn't work for you, since you have the ability to rewrite the file, you should rewrite it to put the data into a separate file, probably in JSON.  That JSON file will be much easier to alter.

```
my $data;
sub getDataStructure {
    $data ||= loadDataStructure("some_config.json");
    return $data;
}
```

If you can't have a separate file, you can put the JSON in a [`__DATA__` section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors) at the end of the file and read it from the special `DATA` filehandle.

```
my $data;
sub getDataStructure {
    $data ||= loadDataStructure();
    return $data;
}

require JSON;
sub loadDataStructure {
    my $json = join '', <DATA>;
    return JSON->new->decode($json);
}

1;

__DATA__
"xyz": {
    "pqr": ...
}
```

It is far easier for another program to read everything after `__DATA__` as JSON, alter it, and write it back out after `__DATA__`.

If for some reason THAT doesn't work, then instead of altering `$var` in place you can simply add to it.

```
my $var = {
    ...blah blah blah...
};

sub getDataStructure() {
  return $var;
}

# These lines are added at the end.
$var->{new_thing} = { new => "stuff" };
$var->{another_new_thing} = { other => "stuff" };

1;
```

This is a maintenance nightmare, but it's much easier to append to the end of the .pm file than it is to alter the middle of a data structure.  Take care to leave the true value at the end, or eliminate that problem by using [true](https://metacpan.org/pod/true).

Comment: This makes it easier for me. Thanks for the answer. And yes, $var and getDataStructure are not the actual names :)

Comment: The real problem is not altering private variable in .pm file. Instead it is for the other users to have an external script that can manipulate this .pm and add new entries. I understand that it is a bad mess I am dealing with but I do not have any option at this point either.

Comment: @KedarJoshi Moving the data into a much easier to manipulate JSON file would seem to solve that problem. Is there a piece you're not telling us?

Comment: Yes, JSON Solution indeed works for me. I will have a separate file in JSON format to store my data, Thanks a lot