# Getting value of a HASH in Perl Mason

Tags: perl, redirect, hash, mason

I have an object which looks like this

```
my $result;
$result->{success} = 0;
$result->{error} = {errorType => "SHIT_ERROR"};
```

When I try to print it using

```
print "result ".\$result;
```

It prints

> HASH(0xc191a768)

How can I actually get its content ?

At the end of the day, I want to pass this as parameter to my redirect request. Just to add more details to it. @dev-null suggested how to pass it on as json but I want to pass it like - success=0&error[errorType]=.....  Kindly suggest how can that be achieved.

Comment: That's a nasty error ;) But it's unclear exactly what you want to print...the value of `success`? The value of `errorType`? The values of every hash key, including nested structures? For the latter, you can use something like [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) or [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump).

Comment: `print "$result->{success}\n";` and `print "$result->{error}{errorType}\n";`

Comment: You want to seriealize the hash as JSON? `{"success": true, "error": {"errorType": "..."}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a simple hash to json in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463919/how-to-convert-a-simple-hash-to-json-in-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of `$result`, you have to:

```
print $result->{success};
```

and then print `error`, but please note that `error` is a nested hash and if you try to print its value:

```
print $result->{error};
```

you will still get something like `HASH(...)` (you'll have to print the `{errorType}` element of the `{error}` element).

Back to your problem. You say you want to pass this parameter to your redirect request. How do you want to implement your redirect request?

**Using $m->redirect() method**

If you are using `$m->redirect()` I would suggest you to change your `$result` to a simpler structure like this:

```
% my $result = {
%   success => 0,
%   errorType => 'SHIRT_ERROR',
% };
% $m->redirect( make_uri('error_handler', $result), 302);
```

this will make a uri like this one:

```
/error_handler?errorType=SHIRT_ERROR&success=0
```

and the redirect method will redirect to it. Your `error_handerl.mc` then could contain something like this:

```
<%class>
  has 'success';
  has 'errorType';
</%class>
<%init>
  if ($.success eq "0") {
    print $.errorType;
  }
</%init>
```

**Using JSON on $m->redirect()**

It looks like Mason doesn't support a query string like `success=0&error[errorType]=...`

The only alternative I can think of is to serialize the request with JSON like this:

**component.mc**

```
<%init>
use JSON;

my $result;
$result->{success} = 0;
$result->{error} = {errorType => "SHIRT_ERROR"};

my $h = {
  result => encode_json $result
};

$m->redirect(make_uri('/error_handler', $h), 302);
</%init>
```

**error_handler.mc**

```
<%class>
  has 'result';
</%class>
<%init>
  use JSON;

  my $result = decode_json $.result;

  print dh $result;
</%init>
```

the first component will redirect to a url like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/error_handler?result=%7B%22success%22%3A0%2C%22error%22%3A%7B%22errorType%22%3A%22SHIRT_ERROR%22%7D%7D
```

I don't find it too elegant, but it works.

Comment: Hi Fthiella, Thanks a lot for detailed reply. The only thing is that handler expects the $result in the same format, and we can not change it. :( .. Kindly suggest how can I pass the $result without simplifying the structure.

Comment: @Andy897 please see my updated answer. I think you should show us some code, maybe we can suggest you a better approach. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried what you suggested it says - Can't call method "encode_json" on unblessed reference

Comment: @Andy897 are you sure you loaded JSON library correctly? what if you assign `my $json = encode_json $result;` and then `my $h = { 'result' => $json };` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Data::Dump;
dd( $result );
```

or

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( $result );
```

or simply

```
while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %{ $result } ) {
  print "$k => $v\n";
}
```

Comment: And how can I pass it as URL parameter

Comment: @Andy897 You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry about the that. I will create a new question probably

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize the hash as a JSON object you can:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $result;
$result->{success} = 0;
$result->{error} = {errorType => "SHIT_ERROR"};

print encode_json $result; # {"success":0,"error":{"errorType":"SHIT_ERROR"}}
```

Comment: Did the OP mention JSON anywhere?

Comment: @MattJacob Not directly, but it is mentioned that OP want to pass the "object" to a http request: `And how can I pass it as URL parameter` which makes me think of JSON

Comment: True, unless he just wants `key=value&key=value...`, which was my original thought. But that wouldn't make much sense for the nested hash, so maybe JSON is the right answer. ;-)

Comment: @MattJacob Oh didn't think of this, OP can also pass `success=0&error[errorType]=...` which is also a valid query string.

Comment: @dev-null .. Thanks a lot. I want to do it this way success=0&error[errorType]=. ... please suggest how can I do that. THanks a lot again.

Comment: This is how I want it to look (as an example) : URL/?actionResult={"success":1,"action":"action123"}